# Identity server 4 in ifrrame application cant set cookie

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, identityserver4

i am using identity server 4 in normal processing scenario it works fine   but when i am opening our application inside iframe when application tries to set Cookie i am getting error in console 
`Set-Cookie header is ignored in response from url: <URL>. Cookie length should be less than or equal to 4096 characters.` 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cookies created from iframes are called third party cookies. They are blocked by default by some browsers, and others browsers can be configured to block them. Can't you redirect to the identity server ?